# Iphone is not able to open link to google maps directions

Tags: google-maps

i have this code:

```
if(navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1 || navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1 || navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1) {
        window.open("https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=" + lat + "," + lon);


}
else {
        window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/" + lat + "," + lon);
        //window.open("https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=" + lat + "," + lon);
    }
```

I know that lon and lat have correct values. it works on all desktop browsers and on an android phone i have tested (gives me the directions), but when i window.open runs on the iphone it loads google maps and it says "route not found"..

is this code not supposed to work on and ios device?

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods to embed Google Maps URL in your iOS app.

- Using [OpenInGoogleMapsController](https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS) class.
- [URL Scheme method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme).

In the first one it is easy to build links to open a map (or display Street View or directions) directly in Google Maps for iOS. Rather than creating URLs by hand, you can create map requests using Objective-C classes and types, so you can take advantage of all the type-checking and code hinting you've come to expect from Xcode.

For Direction follow this code:

```
GoogleDirectionsDefinition *defn = [[GoogleDirectionsDefinition alloc] init];
defn.startingPoint =
    [GoogleDirectionsWaypoint waypointWithQuery:@"221B Baker Street, London"];
defn.destinationPoint = [GoogleDirectionsWaypoint
    waypointWithLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.498511, -0.133091)];
defn.travelMode = kGoogleMapsTravelModeBiking;
[[OpenInGoogleMapsController sharedInstance] openDirections:defn];
```

To launch the Google Maps app for iOS and optionally perform one of the supported functions, use a URL scheme of the following form:

```
comgooglemaps://?parameters
```

Use the Display Direction scheme to request and display directions between two locations. You can also specify the transportation mode.
An example URL is below to display transit directions between Google NYC and JFK Airport:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit
```

Hope tat Helps!!